# PostgreSQL Autoexplain to a view or table?

Tags: database, postgresql, logging, etl

I want to analyze results of EXPLAIN of many queries. The [autoexplain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module seems excellent for this as it runs the EXPLAIN automatically. One problem though: the output is in the logfile. I want it in some table or view so I can perform analysis.

Does the module offer such functionality or maybe there is some neat way to go about it? I don't feel so comfortable extracting the data from a massive logfile after running a huge amount of queries.

Comment: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pg_stat_plans

Comment: https://github.com/postgrespro/sr_plan